# /dev/null for http requests

Tags: javascript, html, testing

I've found myself writing a number of mockups of websites that make a lot of AJAX calls. I'm really just fiddling with how the sites look and don't have a server backing them. Is there a place I can direct the requests that will eat them, return success, but not actually have any content. In effect, I want the AJAX calls to succeed, but not actually have anything returned.

I view this as a sort of `/dev/null` for the internet.

Comment: I could see this being useful to a limited degree. I almost always "do" something with the data/reply in a success callback, though, so whatever it returns would be important. I don't think it would work, though, with built-in cross-site scripting prevention (especially in Firefox) foiling your plans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create an empty file, and request for that file using relative path.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [mockjax](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/07/mock-your-ajax-requests-with-mockjax-for-rapid-development/), and Google for other AJAX-mocking systems.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you do the AJAX calls. In my case I have a function called doAjaxCall which takes a callback function as argument (executed when the Ajax call returns). For some unit tests I overwrite this function to just do a window.setTimeout() (calling the callback function after the timeout).